# Question on set roster notation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, notation

I have a question regarding how to precisely define a formula of mine.

I have a function which maps words to positive integers, $f: S \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^+$. When I apply this mapping funtion to all elements of a set $ \mathcal{D} = \{s_i\}$, where $s_i$ are all words in a fixed sized vocabulary. Then this mapping function yields a set of positive, unique integers for all of the elements in $\mathcal{D}$. Would this notation be correct: $s_i \in \mathcal{\{D\ | \exists!  s_i f(s_i) \}}$

Comment: The first wrong thing is that $\{\mathcal D\}$ is a set with one element, and that one element is named $\mathcal D$. So, $s_i \in \{\mathcal D\}$ is equivalent to $s_i = \mathcal D$ which I'm sure is not your intention.

Comment: Ah yes, $\mathcal{D}$ is the set of all words in a vocabulary, yes.

Comment: You can edit the post to make any corrections you desire. It is worthwhile to do so, because without correcting an error, the post doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thank you - I have corrected the mistake now.

Comment: Next thing I'm wondering, what is the relation between $S$ and $\mathcal D$?

Comment: @LeeMosher S is the set of all words, and D is the set of words actually existing in the vocabulary. This post was maybe a bit too rushed in hindsight. What I am trying to formulate is that we are interested in all words, but due to the constraints of data, we do not have all possible words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from the comments, my understanding is that $\mathcal D$ is a subset of $S$ which is the set of all words, i.e. $\mathcal D \subset S$.

To answer your question, there are two correct notations for the same set you are asking about, namely:
$$f(\mathcal D) = \{f(s_i) \mid s_i \in \mathcal D\}
$$
The left side of the equation, in words, is "the image under $f$ of the subset $\mathcal D$". The right hand side, in words, is "The set of all $f(s_i)$, such that $s_i$ is an element of $\mathcal D$."

The general pattern here applies to any function $f : X \to Y$, and any subset $A \subset X$:
$$f(A) = \{f(x) \mid x \in A\}
$$
which automatically yields a subset of $Y$.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time both to clear some misunderstandings of mine and providing a useful answer.

Comment: Glad to help... and I fixed a typo in my last formula.